# How to stop flickering form button

Tags: forms, ms-access, button, flicker, visual-glitch

I am making a form in ms-Access and needed buttons. A problem I am sure lots of you got is the flickering of certain button when going over them. I have searched around and found the same problem multiple time and never found the right answer.

People suggested things like changing labels to disabled textbox  but it didn't work. I also tested it without anything else but buttons and it still does it. One of the first suggestion i actually found was disabling the theme, but still nothing. The latest tested suggestion was a pop-up window of the form and it still fail to fix the problem.

If you want to test it, just create a blank form and but multiple button. To see the effect more clearly, disable them all. Then go over them with your mouse multiple time and you'll eventually see the visual-glitch.

Is there reasons why those glitch happen? It seems to have been there for around 10 years. If you got a workaround, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: In Access 2010 I can only reproduce this when switching the form from design to form view, not when normally opening the form. And even then it's (for me) far from being annoying in any way. So my suggested workaround: ignore it.

Comment: Which version of Access?

Comment: @wazz Access 2016